# Usage of hashtable in PowerShell to replace objects

Tags: powershell, data-structures

Let's say I have the following scenario:
An IP address is linked to a particular string and I want to match an action.

Example:

> ```
> IP address: 1.1.1.1
>
> String: "Home"
>
> IP address: 5.5.5.5
>
> String: "Work"
> ```

```
if($IP -eq 1.1.1.1) 

{  
   #Do something with "Home"
}
```

What would I be needing to use to have 'pretty' code instead of multiple if loops ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do here is to create a lookup Hashtable where IP's are the keys, and the corresponding strings are the values:

```
$lookupIP = @{
    '1.1.1.1' = 'Home'
    '5.5.5.5' = 'Work'
    # etcetera
}
```

Now, if you have an ip in a variable, simply do

```
$ip = '1.1.1.1'
# Do something with the corresponding string
Write-Host "$ip will do something with $($lookupIP[$ip])"
```

If you like, you can add a test first to see if the $ip can be found in the lookup table:

```
if ($lookupIP.ContainsKey($ip)) {
    Write-Host "$ip will do something with $($lookupIP[$ip])"
}
else {
    Write-Warning "IP '$ip' was not found in the hashtable.."
}
```

Comment: @KahnKah `$lookupIP[$ip]` will print `Home` if the value of $ip was `'1.1.1.1'`, and it prints `Work` when the value of $ip was `'5.5.5.5'`